# Is it possible to send friend requests via Android Facebook SDK 3.0?

Tags: java, android, facebook, sdk, dialog

I'm trying to send friend requests from the Android SDK for Facebook. I had the opportunity to ask a Facebook engineer and he said friend requests were currently not supported in Android. So I think I'm stuck redirecting the user to the browser. My question is how do I do that? This is my code so far: (It doesn't work)

```
private void sendRequestDialog()
{
String USER_ID = "stack.overflow.123";

Bundle params = new Bundle();

params.putString("id", USER_ID);

WebDialog requestsDialog = (
    new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(getActivity(),
        Session.getActiveSession(),
        params))
        .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values, FacebookException error)
            {
                if(error != null)
                {
                    if(error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Request cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    final String requestId = values.getString("request");
                    if (requestId != null)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Request sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Request cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }   
            }

        })
        .build();
requestsDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a WebView in your activity and then

```
webView.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com/dialog/friends/?"+
  "id=brent&"+
  "app_id=123050457758183&"+
  "redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html");
```